# cast between Dictionary<T1,someEnum> and Dictionary<T3,someEnum> where T1:T3 Throws an Error

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary, collections

I have the following code (the names are for the example purpose only):

Some functions that provide me data as dictionaries:

```
public Dictionary<IMayor, SocialStatus> GetMayorSocialStatuses()
{
    //Do Stuff
}

public Dictionary<IJanitor, SocialStatus> GetJanitorSocialStatuses()
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

I have then tried to add these results to a dictionary of type `IPerson`.

Both `IJanitor` and `IMayor` implement `IPerson`.

assuming I will have no issue, I have tried to do the following:

```
public Dictionary<IPerson,SocialStatus> GetPersonsSocialStatuses()
{
    var dict=new Dictionary<IPerson,S ocialStatus>();

    foreach(var mayorKvp in GetMayorSocialStatuses())
    {
        dict.Add(mayorKvp.Key,mayorKvp.Value);
    }

    foreach(var janitorKvp in GetJanitorSocialStatuses())
    {
        dict.add(janitorKvp.Key,janitorKvp.Value);
    }
}
```

worked like charm but the foreach looks digusting.

I have tried replacing them with this extension Method:

```
public static Dictionary<IPerson,SocialStatus> AddRange(
                            this Dictionary<IPerson,SocialStatus> dict, 
                            Dictionary<IPerson,SocialStatus> inputDict)
{
     foreach(var kvp in inputDict)
     {
         dict.add(kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
     }

     return dict;;
}
```

but by doing so, i recieved a compilation error that it can not convert from dictionary of type `IMayor,SocialStatus` to `IPerson,SocialStatus`.

After investigating the issue, I realized they are not castable due to a manner called "close generic type" which means the inheritance does not move along to the dictionary and the cast can not be made.

Question is: how can I solve the issue then?

Isn't there a cleanier way to do so?

(because if the providers weren't in the same class/a static class, I was screwed)

I am not binded to a specific version of .NET so any solution will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error is right - you cannot assign concrete type of dictionary (parametrized with one type of key) to another, different (with other key type) - types doesn't match (as you mentioned).
One possible solution could be changing extension method arguments to accept `IDictionary` as parameter. Unfortunotely it also won't help - becaues that interface is parametrized invariant ([convariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Possible solution:

```
public static Dictionary<IPerson, string> AddRange<TPerson>(
                    this Dictionary<IPerson, string> dict, 
                    Dictionary<TPerson, string> inputDict)
    where TPerson : IPerson
{
    foreach (var kvp in inputDict)
    {
        dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    return dict;
}
```